# "Add a page" link create new Wiki Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki, wiki-pages

Is it possible in SharePoint Online to change the "Add a page" link (from the Cog menu) to create a new Wiki page instead of a Site page? I'm sure our instance used to do this.

Comment: We've been in the same situation. We wonder why and when the "Add a page" button defaulted away from the 'site page' or the 'web part page' content type, to the 'wiki page' content type? Suspecting it's related to a SharePoint update; would be good to obtain clarification on this.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to your

Site Contents / Site Pages
and click on the 'Files' tab,
'New document' + down arrow in the 'Files' ribbon,

you are given the choice of the three different page content types, with 'Site Page' as the 1st choice, rather than wiki page.

It's also good practice for front-end users to go via their Site Pages library so they can check which pages have already been created, before they create a new one.

Comment: While I agree, the objective is to make SharePoint easy to use with as few steps as possible. This is more steps and will cause more reluctance to adopt SharePoint.

Comment: Not sure about voting answer down. MS themselves are making their system less easy to use. How about voting MS down instead? More steps improving practice and content management cannot be a bad thing, if end user are properly explained about best practice and the reason for doing things a certain way.

Comment: I didn't vote it down, someone else did.

Comment: No worry, @MrShoes . :)